# What type does it->first give?

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map

Consider the following code:

```
  static std::unordered_map<std::string, Info> stringCollection;

  auto& [it, inserted] = stringCollection.try_emplace(pString);
  if (inserted) {
    it->second.str = &it->first;
  }
  return it->second;
```

This line `it->second.str = &it->first` is supposed to copy the address of the key (pointer) - but I cannot seem to verify if this will be the case (cannot find reference). Basicly does `it->first` give me a copy or reference ?

Comment: You could guess by yourself: what would happen if `if->first` was a value rather than a reference? `&it->first` would be taking the address of a temporary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to remove the `&` after `auto` because `try_emplace` does not return references:

```
auto [it, inserted] = stringCollection.try_emplace(pString);
```

In this case, the type of `it` is `std::unordered_map<std::string, Info>::iterator` which satisfies [*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) which implies [*LegacyInputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator):

- `it->m` is equivalent to `(*it).m`;
- `*it` returns `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference` (where `It` is the type of `it`).

So the type of `*it` in your case is `std::pair<const std::string, Info>&` (a reference), so if you access its member `first`, you get a reference to a `const std::string` as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator holds the key/value pair. So ->first will give a an std::string as reference